# Read string sent to socket from IRC python script in Actionscript 3 Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sockets

I'm trying to find a simple way to read text strings sent from a python script running on an IRC client into my Adobe Flash document so I can choose how they are displayed within the flash.

I have had help from Mrs to create the following AS3 code, but I get the following error :

An error occurred: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2031: Socket Error. URL: 127.0.0.1"]

Document Class for my flash file (loaded first in flash document):

```
package
{
    import Mrs.SocketMessageEvent;
    import Mrs.SocketTest;

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.system.Security;

    public class Temp_Example2 extends Sprite
    {
        protected var socket:SocketTest;
        public function Temp_Example2()
        {
            this.socket = new SocketTest();
            this.socket.addEventListener(SocketMessageEvent.MESSAGE_RECEIVED, onSocketMessage);
            flash.system.Security.allowDomain("*");
            flash.system.Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
            this.socket.connect("127.0.0.1", 7001);
        }

        protected function onSocketMessage(e:SocketMessageEvent):void 
        {
            var date:Date = new Date();
            trace(date.hoursUTC + ":" + date.minutesUTC + ":" + date.secondsUTC + " Incoming message: " + e.message);
        }
    }
}
```

SocketTest Class (In Mrs subfolder):

```
package Mrs
{
    import flash.errors.IOError;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.Socket;

    public class SocketTest extends Socket 
    {
        protected var _message:String;

        public function SocketTest() 
        {
            super();
            this._message = "";

            this.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, socketConnected);
            this.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, socketClosed);
            this.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, socketData);
            this.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, socketError);
            this.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, socketError);
        }

        protected function socketData(event:ProgressEvent):void 
        {
            var str:String = readUTFBytes(bytesAvailable);

            //For this example, look for \n as a message terminator
            var messageParts:Array = str.split("\n");

            //There could be multiple messages or a partial message, 
            //pass on complete messages and buffer any partial
            for (var i = 0; i < messageParts.length; i++) 
            {
                this._message += messageParts[i];
                if (i < messageParts.length - 1) 
                {
                    this.notifyMessage(this._message);
                    this._message = "";
                }
            }
        }

        protected function notifyMessage(value:String):void 
        {
            this.dispatchEvent(new SocketMessageEvent(SocketMessageEvent.MESSAGE_RECEIVED, value));
        }

        protected function socketConnected(event:Event):void 
        {
            trace("Socket connected");
        }

        protected function socketClosed(event:Event):void 
        {
            trace("Connection was closed");
            //TODO: Reconnect if needed
        }

        protected function socketError(event:Event):void 
        {
            trace("An error occurred:", event);
        }
    }
}
```

SocketMessageEvent Class (Again in Mrs subfolder):

```
package Mrs
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class SocketMessageEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const MESSAGE_RECEIVED:String = "messageReceived";

        protected var _message:String;

        public function SocketMessageEvent(type:String, message:String = "", bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
            this._message = message;
        }

        public function get message():String
        {
            return this._message;
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked and some people suggested this may be a compile options error but not sure how find the option to change.

Comment: you should take a look here: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/44247 the last post contains some links that might help. I had the same problems with a xml socket. You also need a socket policy file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should use XMLSocket. It has a native implementation of splitting messages by \n. Nice and clean :)

Now for your problem, its obvious to me that the server is not on. If it is, make sure it binds to the same address and port. Your problem may be serverside, but without the code to look at, we can't tell. Perhaps the server made a silent crash? Perhaps you forgot or somehow the startServer() or whatever method didn't take?

Comment: Great thanks, I've now got my python server running on port 7001 and it connected without error.

Comment: @Zac you are welcome. I experienced the same problem, i got my ports wrong :D please mark the answer as correct. thank you

Comment: Accepted as correct however it stopped working again, so I'm not sure the problem is 100% sorted.

Comment: perhaps your server is crashing because an error? do you have a log and error file in which you dump each and everything that happens? :D